# AlertDialog.dismiss()?

Tags: android, dialog

I am new in android and I am learning from developer.android.com site. Then I came across to AlertDialog.dismiss() where in site it is written that

> This method Dismiss dialog and remove it from the screen. This method can be
>   invoked safely from any thread. Note that you should not override this
>   method to do cleanup when the dialog is dismissed, instead implement
>   that in onStop().

But I did not understand the mean of this line-

> Note that you should not override this method to do cleanup when the
>   dialog is dismissed, instead implement that in onStop()

what is the mean of above line?

`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AlertDialog.dismiss()`  uses to dismiss the dialog if it's opened up as describe at developer site

`Note that you should not override this method to do cleanup when the dialog is dismissed, instead implement that in onStop()`.

The above statement simply means that as we used to garbage collect object which is no more referenced in `class` and avail for  `garbage collect`. They are simpling stating that the approach like `avail for garbage collection` also applies in here but there are eligible inside `onStop()` of `Activity`.

So better to use it as `onStop()` as it's the last call of `Activity Life Cycle` which can dismissed your `alertdialog`. If it incase is there on the screen without dismissal.